# How to reposition HTML element to a different part of hierarchy based on the breakpoint?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, responsive-design, css-grid

This is some html and css that uses flexbox to position an element (colored in yellow). In a large breakpoint it appears in one place but in a small breakpoint it needs to be in a different part of the hierarchy. So it's not as simple as just repositioning its order but actually moving it to a different place.

How can I do this using just CSS and flexbox? If that's not possible then I could use CSS grid. Would prefer not to have to use javascript unless there's no other way.

```css
.one {
  background-color: lightgray;
}

.two {
  background-color: red;
}

.three {
  background-color: blue;
}

.element {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<h1>large breakpoint</h1>
<div>
  <div style="display:flex">
    <div class="one">
      <div>one</div>
    </div>
    <div class="element">
      possible position 1
    </div>
    <div class="two">two</div>
    <div class="three">three</div>
  </div>
</div>

<h1>small breakpoint</h1>
<div>
  <div style="display:flex">
    <div class="one">
      <div>one</div>
    </div>
    <div class="two">two</div>
    <div class="three">three</div>
  </div>
  <div class="element">
    possible position 2
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Refer here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Ordering_Flex_Items

Comment: @Saravanan that doesn't let you change its position in the hierarchy, just reordering within the same part of the hierarchy.

Comment: Sadly this is one of several cool features in the 2003 Generated and Replaced Contents Draft that never got implemented. In this case, it would have been the [move-to](https://www.w3.org/TR/2003/WD-css3-content-20030514/#moving) feature. As it is, you'll need JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sure you can achieve what you want with the [`order`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Ordering_Flex_Items#the_order_property) property. Here's an example where an element is in a different order than the order in which it was declared.

You can set the `order` property in each breakpoint to match your needs.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.item {
  border: 0.025em solid black;
  padding: 1em;
}

#special-item {
  order: 3;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<h1>Large breakpoint</h1>
<div class="container">
  <div class="item">One</div>
  <div class="item">Two</div>
  <div class="item">Three</div>
  <div class="item">Four</div>
</div>

<h1>Small breakpoint</h1>
<div class="container">
  <div class="item">One</div>
  <div id="special-item" class="item">Two</div>
  <div class="item">Three</div>
  <div class="item">Four</div>
</div>
```

Comment: It's not as simple as reordering the elements but moving it to a different place in the hierarchy.

Comment: I've updated the example to match the behavior in your question. If it's still not what you need, then would you please clarify what you are looking for?